# reasonml record vs JS object

Tags: ocaml, record, reason, bucklescript

Say I define the following types:

```
type queueParams = {
  durable: bool
};

class type amqpChannelT = [@bs] {
  pub assertQueue: string => queueParams => Js.Promise.t(unit);
};
```

Then calling the following:

```
channel##assertQueue("exampleQueue", {"durable": bool});
```

Results in:

```
This has type:
    {. "durable": bool}
  But somewhere wanted:
    queueParams (defined as
```

How can I pass the right type of thing? Why is the thing I'm passing not a record? And what is the meaning of that dot notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReasonML interprets these two differently:

```
let jsObject = {"durable": true};
let reasonRecord = {durable: true};
```

Basically, wrapping keys with double-quotes is a short-hand notation for the special Javascript object type `Js.t('a)` - which is currently deprecated.

You can [play around with an example here](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=C4TwDgpgBAjgrhBAFAhgJxQWwM5QLxQDeAUFFACZwYBGANhAFxTUD2LtxAvgNzHH3AoAK2wB5akIgBjQQUIAiSjXrymwNAh78IgmGHxElKOoyjrNvYgClsAOlosA5gCYAFCPGSZAGlhgAlNxAA). Note how the two types are treated differently when converted to Javascript.

Read more about the deprecated syntax here:

https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/object-deprecated

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Very clear. Just one small followup, what does that dot notation syntax mean? the {. ...?

Comment: @AbrahamP The type definition `{. "key": type}` is for any and all `Js.t('a)` (JS special objects). It's what I first noticed as being _off_ in your example. It's very similar to the (closed) object type definition `{. key: type}`, described here: https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/object , but note how the former has its keys wrapped with double-quotes. I'm not certain, but I think this is a special type exposed by Bucklescript, guaranteed to compile to a identically shaped JS object.